# Java- How can I resolve my method cannot be applied to given types error for my TicTacToe game?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a TicTacToe game with methods for initializing the game, displaying the board, showing the game options, say whose turn it is, check winners, add a move, restart the game, check if the board is full, and play the game. I'm having issues with my add a move method and play game method.

```
  public boolean addMove(int row, int column) {
  boolean nonacceptable = true;
  while (nonacceptable) {
     System.out.println("Which row and column would you like to enter your mark? Enter the row and column between 0 and 2 separated by a space.");
     row = input.nextInt();
     column = input.nextInt();
     if ((row >= 0 && row <=2) && (column >= 0 && column <=2)) { //make sure user entered a number between 0 and 2
        if (gameBoard[row][column] != ' ') 
           System.out.println("Sorry, this position is not open!");

        else {
           gameBoard[row][column] = currentMark;
           nonacceptable = false;
        }
     }   
     else 
        System.out.println("That position is not between 0 and 2!");
     }
     return nonacceptable;
```

}

And this is my play method:

```
  public void letsPlay() {
  while (true) {
     displayBoard();
     gameOptions();
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     if (choice == 1) {
        if (addMove()) {
           displayBoard();
           checkWinner();
           System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (!boardFull()) {
           displayBoard();
           System.out.println("Board full!");
           System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
           whoseTurn();
        }
     }
     else if (choice == 2) 
        restart();
     else if (choice == 3) 
        System.exit(0);
     else 
        System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
}
```

And when I compile, I'm getting this error: TicTacToe.java:110: error: method addMove in class TicTacToe cannot be applied to given types;
            if (addMove()) {
                ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite clear.

your addMove function signature accept two arguments

```
public boolean addMove(int row, int column) { 
                         ^          ^
```

Whenever you want to call or use addMove function, you must follow the rule that you defined in your signature function.

So, the solution is to pass two arguments which has type int in the place you call your addMove function ,and this issue goes away.

Note: [Read more about how to define a function and call it in Java](https://blog.udemy.com/java-methods/)

Comment: two* (you got a typo)

Answer (score 1):

You only declared `addMove` method which accepts two int arguments.

```
public boolean addMove(int row, int column) { ...
```

If you don't have declaration of `addMove` with no arguments (`public boolean addMove() {`), you can't call it call it like that: `addMove()`.

According to your code, you don't need the arguments because you're assigning to them values from a `Scanner` anyway, so change the declaration of the method to:

```
public boolean addMove() {
    //declare the variables
    int row, column;
    ...
}
```